# How to get workspace ID of Azure Log Analytics using az CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

How to get workspace ID of Azure Log Analytics using `az` CLI ?

I want to use this ID in a script when creating AKS

```sh
az aks create --name myk8s --resource-group rg-myk8s \
  --workspace-resource-id XXX
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run the following command to get the Workspace ID:

```
az monitor log-analytics workspace show --resource-group MyResourceGroup --workspace-name MyWorkspace --query customerId -o tsv
```

[image]

Comment: You are right! The `customerId` from the query is the same as Workspace ID